# Multiple specification in python string format

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

I want to specify a certain width for my string and also specify the number of digit.

I can each of these formatting separately:

```
print '{:13}'.format(1.0/3)
print '{:.2f}'.format(1.0/3)
```

I could compound like this:

```
print '{:13}'.format('{:.2f}'.format(1.0/3))
```

But how can I do both elegantly in 1 go?

Comment: Are you looking for `'{:13.2f}'`?

Comment: Excellent, thanks!